# Make a Modal at the Top Left Corner of the Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a modal created using Jquery UI Library(http://jqueryui.com/dialog). Below is my code:

```
$("#mypreview_modal").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: true,
    height: 520,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: 525, 
    buttons: {
        "Print": function() {                                  
        },
        "Close": function() {                   
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }        
});
```

I want to position my dialog at the top left corner of the window with the right vertical scrollbar at the top right corner of the window.

[image]

Comment: using css if #mypreview_modal position is absolute . then add top:0; left:0; in css code

Answer (score 1):

```
#mypreview_modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
```

Comment: as per screen shot need to add left:0; ?

Comment: yes if you want it on left corner than use left:0; or if you want in right than right:0;

Comment: yes fine bu tquestion is about put pop up in left side . :)